# bert-extractive-summarizer import warning/error

Tags: python, nlp, pytorch

I am trying to use `from summarizer import Summarizer, TransformerSummarizer` (a.k.a. bert-extractive-summarizer) library in python to do text summerization with models like Bert, Gpt-2 and others...

But when I try this import I get an error (ie. warning but I can't run my code):

```
UserWarning: "sox" backend is being deprecated. The default backend will be changed to "sox_io" backend in 0.8.0 and "sox" backend will be removed in 0.9.0. Please migrate to "sox_io" backend. Please refer to https://github.com/pytorch/audio/issues/903 for the detail.
  warnings.warn(
```

then traceback and at the end this:

```
AttributeError: module transformers.models.cpm has no attribute CpmTokenizer
```

Who can I fix this?

PS: I saw on the github that the solution to torchaudio problem is to use `torchaudio.set_audio_backend("sox_io")` , but how should I use it is not clarified if anyone knows the solution to the problem let them write a detailed step by step process.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest installing package tensorflow-gpu before importing any transformers library, as it internally checks if TensorFlow is installed.

```
pip install tensorflow-gpu
```

more information on how to install Tensorflow with GPU on [Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip)